# Como configurar apache2 para python 3.5.2

Tags: python, apache, aplicação-web, python-3.x, cgi

Tenho tentado estudar programação para web com Python, mas não consigo configurar o servidor no meu computador, alguém pode me ajudar? Seja me indicando como configurar ou me fornecendo um local para baixar já configurado (de preferência como configurar, não quero ficar dependente). Desde já agradeço.

Quando tento rodar o localhost para ver o resultado, aparece o seguinte código:

```
#!C:/Program Files/Python35
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

print("<p>Olá Mundo</p>")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Entendendo por que não se usa mais CGI**

Essa configuração que você quer não é tão difícil - mas me reservo o direito de não responde-la de imediato (em uma atualização, adicionei essa informação ao final da resposta)

Quem está acostumado com PHP, ou acha documentação antiga - ou mesmo procura por programação Web na biblioteca padrão do Python, pode, como você, acabar achando que se usa Python com CGI ainda hoje.

Isso não é mais verdade. Há uns 8 anos, pelo menos. CGI é um modelo de aplicação pra Web que existe desde os primeiros tempos de dos servidores como o Apache - e a ideia é que em vez do servidor Web servir um arquivo estático do disco, ele executa um outro programa completo, e a saída desse programa (isso é, tudo o que ele imprime na saída padrão) é o conteúdo enviado na resposta à requisição HTTP. O custo (CPU, memória, acesso a disco, etc...) de se iniciar todo o runtime do Python num processo a parte, carregar o programa todo, para resposta a uma única página é algo completamente inaceitável - quase impensável, hoje em dia.

Com uma outra coisa que é bem diferente de hoje: cada programa se localiza fisicamente no sistema de arquivos na posição dada pela URL: ou seja, para um sistema com várias views diferentes, você teria um programa distinto para cada view.

**Os conceitos - e alguns pacotes, usados hoje para Python para Web**

Então o "jeito certo" de se programar Python para Web hoje em dia é usar um Framework já pronto. Em geral os Frameworks utilizam, internamente, um protocolo do Python chamado "WSGI" (Web Server Gateway Interface) - através desse protocolo se conecta a estrutura do Python com um servidor HTTP externo, se for desejado - como o apache ou o nginx.

Mas melhor ainda: para estudar e desenvolver o protótipo do seu sistema   - e mesmo para colcoar em produção em alguns casos, você não precisa configurar esse servidor externo.  Há projetos em Python puro, e outros em C que podem servir um projeto com WSGI diretamente na Web - como [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [gUnicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) dentre outros - e a conexão final com o Apache, no caso, é feita com o [Mod_WSGI](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Mas, voltando aos Frameworks: eles são projetos que provêm uma infraestrutura, bibliotecas, e várias utilidades, dentre funções e classes para permitir o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação Web moderna. Em Python existem dezenas de Frameworks -  e certamente mais de 10 em desenvolvimento ativo e mantidos atualizados.
Dentre os mais populares estão o [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) e o [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Mas ha'outros como Web2py, Bottle, Pyramid, etc... cada um com alguams caracterpsiticas próprias.  Alguns, como o Flask e o Bottle são conhecidos como "microframeworks" por que trazem de forma rápida tudo o  que você precisa para começar um aplicação Web - mesmo que seja simples. Não obrigam ao uso de um banco de dados, nem suporte a login de usuários, etc... Mas todas essas coisas são "plugáveis" através de outros projetos bem mantidos e integrados.

Então, é algo bem subjetivo, mas dentre os vários existentes, eu diria que o Flask pode ser um jeito de começar a estudar Python para Web.

**Passo a passo para um "alô mundo" Web - Python + Flask**

Para criar um "Alô mundo" WEB com Flask siga esses passos (no Linux - Windows é mais chato para linha de comando - mas são os mesmos passos, adaptando-se os prefixos de diretórios, etc... (Pode ser `C:\Python3\bin\Python`, em vez de apenas `python3`, por exemplo):

1) Com o Python 3.5 ou posterior instalado, crie um virtualenv com o comando:
`python3 -m venv alomundo`. Em seguida, ative o seu ambiente virtual: `cd alomundo`, `source bin/activate`.  Pronto, agora você pode isntalar uma versão do Flask que fica independe da instalação do Python do seu sistema - permitindo que você trabalhe com projetos diferentes que usem versões distintas do Flask e de outros pacotes

2) Digite `pip install flask` - isso vai trazer o flask e todos os pacotes que são necessários para sua execução - inclusive um servidor web de teste -  o Waitress.

3) Digite o seu programa que pode ser algo como:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return("<h1>Alô mundo!<p>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

(Você vai ter que fazer o tutorial e estudar a documentação do Flask, mas uma grande diferença aqui para quem vem do PHP: O nome do seu arquivo é 100% independente do que aparece na URL - é no decorador que precede a função de view `hello` que eu coloco o caminho da URL ao qual essa view responderá)

**Apesar de tudo - como configurar CGI no Apache**

Você precisa editar algumas configurações no seu `httpd.conf` do apache  - 
a forma mais simples é mandar carregar o `mod_cgi` e usar uma diretiva `script-alias` que transforma uma parte da URL num mapeamento para um diretório específico. Aí, todos os arquivos nesse diretório passam automaticamente a serem executados como scripts CGI, em vez de serem servidos diretamente.

No Windows, experimente colocar no seu httpd.conf as diretivas:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "c:\meus_scripts\"
```

E colocar seus programas de teste na pasta "meus_scripts". Apesar de não ser  mais usado, conseguir fazer alguns exemplos direto em CGI pode ser muito didático em termos de entender *como* a Web funciona no nível do HTTP - por isso inclui essa configuração como você perguntou. O seu programa de "Hello World" deve funcionar normalmente.

Para ver a documentação completa de como configurar CGI no apache, veja:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html

**Executando CGI sem configurar o Apache**

O Python também vem com um servidor HTTP de testes que suporta CGI - e você pode rodar o seu programa acima diretamente, sem precisar instalar mais nada (nem o apache). Para isso, copie-o para uma pasta chamada `cgi-bin` e, na pasta acima dessa, inicie o servidor de testes com o comando `python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000` - Em seguida, acesse a página em `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/<nome-do-script.py>` .

(Usuários de Linux, não esqueçam de marcar os scripts CGI como executáveis (com o comando `chmod` ou pela interface gráfica))

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, vou dar pesquisada sobre o Flask. Queria o CGI apenas por questão de aprendizado, mas ainda sou iniciante em programação web com qualquer linguagem, só domino bem HTML, CSS e js por enquanto e realmente não me familiarizo com PHP e sempre gostei de Python. Valeu a atenção.

Comment: +1 pelo simples fato de ignorar a pergunta original sobre CGI e ajudar a resolver o real problema da pessoa de uma forma muito melhor.

Comment: A pessoa pode estar querendo apenas saber por hobby, por exemplo criando um IDE pessoal... fazendo testes, curiosidade científica.