# Como criar um site com o pc de servidor usando apenas Python?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

## explicação resumida

pense no site como um app. eu preciso criar um app no celular que acesse funções no pc através de comandos. no que tange ao tratamento dos comandos e a chamada de funções eu até entendo como fazer, o problema é que eu não consigo trabalhar a transferência de dados web para pc. infelizmente minha área não é web, por isso agradeceria muito a ajuda. '''independente de usar ou não python, minha única real restrição é não usar javascript e html... css, xhtml, django, ou outras linguagens são permitidas'''

ps: não precisar ser online, um servidor local basta

## explicação longa

eu tenho um amigo que é o famoso fanboy de javascript, e olha que eu nem sabia que isso existia, ele basicamente propõe que js deve ser usado em tudo, inclusive no lugar das linguagens de baixo nível. eu entendo o valor de js, também como os das outras linguagens, e, como tal, não poderia simplesmente me abster de ir contra essa tese. a escolha de python não foi arbitrária, é a minha linguagem mãe e a que eu mais domino, assim como o sistema que me propus a fazer pois ele será realmente útil pra mim.
assim, eu decidi desenvolver uma ferramenta dentro do campo predominante de js, a web, que facilitasse minha vida como desenvolvedor python.

Comment: Sua pergunta é demasiadamente ampla e há muitos conceitos por trás que você precisará aprender para fazer o que deseja. Você precisará configurar um servidor HTTP em sua máquina local, precisará configurar toda sua rede para permitir acessos externos à ela, configurar para seu servidor se comunicar com a interface do Python para, então, executar o código que necessita. Veja essa pergunta: [Como configurar apache2 para python 3.5.2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177499/5878) para ter uma noção inicial. E estude HTTP, é muito importante conhecer o protocolo que está utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

PAra responder a pequenas chamadas via HTTP com funções arbitrárias de Python, o mais simples é usar um microframework como o Flask - de uma olhada no hello world do Flask mesmo - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/

Django é uma boa, mas ele já vai criar um projeto em que é mais chato de configurar urls de view, e assume que você vai usar um banco de dados com ORM, que pode nem ser o seu caso.